# Hibernate Relationship Error

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I am currently trying to ponder how to fix the relationship between the entities in hibernate within my project. The project is basically a music management thingy, and so there are Users, Songs and Artists.

One User can have multiple Songs, one Song can be favoured be multiple people.
One Song only has one Artist.

The entities look like this:
User:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Song> songs;
```

Song:

```
public class Song implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "songs")
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToOne
    private Artist artist;
```

Artist:

```
public class Artist implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artist")
    private List<Song> songs;
```

And within a method I am using a simple JPARepository to save some changes:

```
artistRepository.save(song.getArtist());
songRepository.save(song);
userRepository.save(requestUser);
```

Then I get the error that I have to save the trasient entity song first which makes sense. I figured I screwed up somewhere when linking the entites. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: please can you post all your entity code ?

Comment: You have to provide join table name in menyToMany relationships

Comment: @arthur yes I can

Comment: @janith1024 how does that work? I am new to hibernate

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/ check this

Comment: Now I have it like this and I still got the same error:
https://imgur.com/a/QFHwx

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace please?